# case + how to implement equal or less or greater in case syntax

Tags: linux, bash, shell-scripting, ksh

my target is to verify the range of number with (only with -  case + esac )  , and print the range

so for example

if number is between 0-80 , case will print

```
 >=0<=80
```

or if range is between 81-100 then case will print

```
 >=81<=100
```

and so on....

the problem with my script print only >=0<=90 only if number between 0-9 ?

how to fix my script , so it will print according to number range ?

```
#!/bin/ksh

read number 

case $number in 
    [0-80])  echo ">=0<=80";; 
    [81-100]) echo ">=81<=100";; 
    [101-120]) echo ">=101<=120";;
    [121-300]) echo ">=121<=300";;
esac
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In zsh (which ksh is symlinked to on my system) you need to use `<>` for numerical ranges:

```
case $number in
    <0-80>)  echo ">=0<=80";;
    <81-100>) echo ">=81<=100";;
    <101-120>) echo ">=101<=120";;
    <121-300>) echo ">=121<=300";;
esac
```